# stm32wl55jc adjust adc dma sample rate for microphone

Tags: stm32, adc, signal, c

I am using stm32wl55jc1. I want to use accelerometer at 50khz and microphone at 2khz (2048). I am trying to make fft. With pooling adc method, I can do that easily.
I shouldn't blok the cpu so I need to use dma.
Sampling Time: 16 ADC clock cycle((12.5+1.5)*1/24MHz=0.58333µs)

here is my adjustment of adc:
[image]

here is my code:

```
uint32_t ADC_VAL[128];
void HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback(ADC_HandleTypeDef* hadc)
{
FFT(ADC_VAL,128,2048);
}
HAL_ADC_Start_DMA(&hadc,ADC_VAL,128);
```

As I said before, I can use fft without problem with pooling and timer. I am writing 0.5 mikrosecond delay and thats it. I want to use dma but I couldn't manage it. How can I adjust sample rate with dma ?

Comment: What useful info do you hope to get from the microphone when you're only sampling at 2Hz? Or did you mean to write 2**k**Hz?

Comment: @brhans 2khz sorry